# 'Page cannot be found' after completing Woocommerce checkout using Cardsave gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

So since updating to Woocommerce 2.1, customers placing an order through the checkout are met with 'page cannot be found' once completing their card details through the Cardsave website. Their order has been successfully placed and comes through to the Woocommerce orders screen but they don't know this!

I know it is something to do with Woocommerce now using endpoints but I have trailed through lots of other questions with similar problems and I just cannot figure out the bit of php code that needs changing.

My website is www.munchkinscakes.com, if any more information is required then I can provide it. Please help as I am tearing my hair out!!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend posting this question on WooThemes forum, you may encounter other users with the same situation there.

http://support.woothemes.com/hc/communities/public/topics

Also, I would check if they offer paid support, you may be able to pay a few hundred dollars to get your issue solved quickly by one of their devs.